# Put data into sheet on timer for excel presentation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working timer in my sheet in a certain cell. I need to populate the sheet with predetmined values (in the macro or references to cell either one) and input the into a templete for a demonstration. Has anyone ever done this. My code is..
The "yeah" sub is NOT done but I wanted to get one piece working. I cannot.

```
Sub timer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Increment_count"
End Sub
Sub Increment_Count()
Range("AE5").Value = Range("AE5") + TimeValue("00:00:01")
timer

Application.Run ("yeah")

End Sub
Sub STOPtimer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Increment_count", Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub yeah()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To 31
If IsError(Cells(i, 39)) = False And IsError(Cells(32, 5)) = False Then
If Cells(i, 38) = Cells(31, 5) Then
Cells(1, 8) = Cells(i, 39)
End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: what isn't exactly working there?? do I get you right that you want to run YEAH each second? I think you could combine all subs into one...

Comment: Yes it has to run every second because at 12:00:10 (10 seconds in) I need it to populate a given cells, and so on and so on.

Comment: Sorry, again, where exactly is your problem?? what is not working?? it stops or what?? are you sure that this line `Cells(1, 8) = Cells(i, 39)` is executed?? you can check it this way- put your cursor there and press F9 and run your main sub next. If it stops there check if there are data to copy...

Answer (score 0):

Are you going for a transitonal type effect with your data slowly populating? I think that is what you are doing. A timer seems somewhat unnecessary for something that is a one time thing like this seems to be.(30 or whatever numbers isn't alot either).

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Sub Macro1()

    Range("B1").Value = "1"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B2").Value = "2"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B3").Value = "3"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B4").Value = "4"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B5").Value = "5"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B6").Value = "6"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B7").Value = "7"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B8").Value = "8"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B9").Value = "9"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B10").Value = "10"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B11").Value = "11"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B12").Value = "12"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B13").Value = "13"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B14").Value = "14"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B15").Value = "15"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B16").Value = "16"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B17").Value = "17"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B18").Value = "18"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B19").Value = "19"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B20").Value = "20"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B21").Value = "21"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B22").Value = "22"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B23").Value = "23"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B24").Value = "24"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B25").Value = "25"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B26").Value = "26"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B27").Value = "27"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B28").Value = "28"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B29").Value = "29"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B30").Value = "30"
    Sleep 1000 'Implements a 1 second delay
    Range("B31").Value = "31"

End Sub
```

This way you can populate groups and change the delay between effects however you want. Although personally for presentation purposes - I would just display the data and be done with it. No need to wow the audience in this regard. Just a personal preference on my part though. Good Luck.